# Slow scrolling background in Javascript or CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to figure out how to make a background image scroll slower than the page contents. I haven't got a clue how it's done. The perfect example of what I'm trying to do [is here](http://james.padolsey.com/)

Is this done in CSS or jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: This used to be called parallax scrolling back when I was a kid and wanted to make games. There seem to be some resources that use the same term out there (e.g. when Googling `jquery parallax scrolling`)

Comment: Javascript. Significantly easier with jQuery, but it also requires special HTML/CSS markers. Cool, simple example at http://inner.geek.nz/javascript/parallax/ . You could also just google `parallax scrolling`.

Comment: @Edwin : Thank you for pointing out the proper name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is made by javascript (jQuery):

```
(function () {
    var a = document.body,
        e = document.documentElement;
    $(window).unbind("scroll").scroll(function () {
        a.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + -(Math.max(e.scrollTop, a.scrollTop) / 8) + "px";
    });
})();
```

Comment: This is briliant! Just remember tu put it at page end or when using jQuery wrap it with `ready` function. Background should have `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

The effect on the link you posted is done in Javascript using jQuery.

If you examine the code of a script of the site **[here](http://james.padolsey.com/wp-content/themes/james.padolsey/m.js?201012)**, you can find:

```
.style.backgroundPosition="0px "+-(Math.max(e.scrollTop,a.scrollTop)/8)+"px"
```

Practically, the `background-position` CSS property is modified on page scrolling calculating Y-axis depending on page scroll position. If you have some knowledge of Javascript, jQuery or Mootools, you can reproduce the effect very easily.

I think it's impossible to do it using only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for high bg images.

```
(function () {
        var body = document.body,
                e = document.documentElement,
                scrollPercent;
        $(window).unbind("scroll").scroll(function () {
            scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
            body.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + scrollPercent + "%";
        });
})();
```