# How to create a parallax background attached to HTML tag?

Tags: jquery, css, background, parallax

I saw the following post which is exactly what I need, except for my background image is not on the body tag it's on the html tag. I've tried all sorts to get it to work but can't figure out how to grab the html tag in jQuery.

[Slow scrolling background in Javascript or CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646912/slow-scrolling-background-in-javascript-or-css)

Is this something simple I'm missing?

Comment: Why is your background image on the `<html>`? Move it to the `<body>` - that's where it should be anyway.

Comment: AFAIK a valid `<html>` tag can't have any background image. Use the `<body>` for the slower scrolling parallax background and a `<div>` layer with the height and width of the body size for the faster one.

Comment: That's a shame, we always style the html tag with css and use another transparent image for the body (not for parallax, just normal use). I'd really like to keep it this way but if it's not going to work then I'll have to have a rethink. Thanks.